# C# Regex to C++ boost::regex

Tags: c#, c++, boost, boost-regex

I have the requirement to match strings in a C++ code of the form

```
L, N{1, 3}, N{1, 3}, N{1, 3}
```

where in the above pseudo-code, `L` is always a letter (upper or lower case) *or* a fullstop (`.` character) and `N` is always numeric `[0-9]`.

So explicitly, we might have `B, 999, 999, 999` or `., 8, 8, 8` but the number of numeric characters is always the same after each `,` and is either 1, 2 or 3 digits in length; so `D, 23, 232, 23` is *not* possible.

In C# I would match this as follows

```
string s = "   B,801, 801, 801 other stuff";
Regex reg = new Regex(@"[\.\w],\s*\d{1,3},\s*\d{1,3},\s*\d{1,3}");
Match m = reg.Match(s);
```

Great. However, I need a similar regex using `boost::regex`. I have attempted

```
std::string s = "   B,801, 801, 801 other stuff";
boost::regex regex("[\\.\w],\s*\d{1,3},\s*\d{1,3},\s*\d{1,3}");
boost::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> results;
boost::regex_match(s, results, regex);
```

but this is giving me `'w' : unrecognized character escape sequence` and the same for `s` and `d`. But from the [documentation](http://www.gps.caltech.edu/~walter/arx/ArX-2.2.4/src/boost/libs/regex/doc/syntax.html) I was under the impression I can use `\d`, `\s` and `\w` without issue.

**What am I doing wrong here?**

---

*Edit. I have switched to `std::regex` as-per a comment above. Now, presumably the regex is the same and the following compiles but the regex does* not *match...*

```
std::string p = "XX";
std::string s = "    B,801, 801, 801 other stuff";
std::regex regex(R"del([\.\w],\s*\d{1,3},\s*\d{1,3},\s*\d{1,3})del");
if (std::regex_match(s, regex))
   p = std::regex_replace(s, regex, "");
```

Comment: C++ has escape characters, just like C# does. It also has raw string literals, just like C# has verbatim strings. For what good it does, C++ also has a standard regular expressions library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\w`, `\s`, and `\d` in your regular expressions. However, that's not what you're doing; you're trying to use `\w` as a character in the string. For there to be a `\` followed by a `w` in the actual string, you need to escape the `\` (same for `s` and `d`, of course):

```
boost::regex regex("[\\.\\w],\\s*\\d{1,3},\\s*\\d{1,3},\\s*\\d{1,3}");
```

As of C++11, you can use [raw string literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) to make your code even more similar to the C# version:

```
boost::regex regex(R"del([\.\w],\s*\d{1,3},\s*\d{1,3},\s*\d{1,3})del");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have ran the regex using `boost` and `std::regex` but neither match for the above regex...

Comment: @Killercam Does replacing `[\\.\\w]` with `[\\._[:alnum:]]` (with `std::regex`) work for you?

Comment: No, if I have `std::string s = "    B,801, 801, 801 other stuff";` and `std::regex regex("\\w");` then `std::regex_match(s, regex)` returns false!?

Comment: @Killercam Correct. [`std::regex_match`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match) attempts to match an entire string. I think what you want is [`std::regex_search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search)